# Output block in particular region from custom module drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a custom module that spits out a form using the drupal form API. What I'd like to do is output a block (a custom menu) in a particular region of the page (using block regions would be the best way I'm guessing.) As of now, the block renders in the top left everytime. How can I output the menu block in a particular region of the page?

```
function client_menu(){

 $items=array();

 $items['campaign']=array(

   'title'=>'Campaign Manager',
   'description'=>'Area for clients to manage their campaigns',
   'page callback'=>'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments'=>array('client_campaign'),
   'access arguments'=>array('access client administration'),
   'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM   
 );

 return $items;

}

function client_campaign(){

$block = module_invoke('menu', 'block_view', 'menu-client-admin');
print render($block);

//a bunch of form API stuff...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying wouldn't work as you are creating a page by
creating a menu item. Rather you should visit your block administration
page at www.example.com/admin/structure/block. Here you will see the list
of all your blocks and available regions in your theme to assign
the blocks.

Here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot of block administration page]

In the screenshot where you are seeing the select list with `none` as selected. This list will let you place your block in the available region.